# User defined function - issue with return values

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dplyr, subscript

I regularly come up against the issue of how to categorise dataframes from a list of dataframes according to certain values within them (E.g. numeric, factor strings, etc). I am using a simplified version using vectors here.

After writing messy for loops for this task a bunch of times, I am trying to write a function to repeatedly solve the problem. The code below returns a subscripting error (given at the bottom), however I don't think this is a subscripting problem, but to do with my use of return.

As well as fixing this, I would be very grateful for any pointers on whether there are any cleaner / better ways to code this function.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

#dummy data
segmentvalues <- c('1_P', '2_B', '3_R', '4_M', '5_D', '6_L')
trialvec <- vector()

for (i in 1:length(segmentvalues)){
  for (j in 1:20) {
    trialvec[i*j] <- segmentvalues[i]
  }

}

#vector categorisation
vcategorise <- function(categories, data) {
  #categorises a vector into a list of vectors
  #requires plyr and dyplyr
  assignment <- list()
  catlength <- length(categories)

  for (i in 1:length(catlength)){
    for (j in 1:length(data)) {
      if (any(contains(categories[i], ignore.case = TRUE, 
as.vector(data[j])))) {
      assignment[[i]][j] <- data[j]
    }
  }
  }
  return (assignment)
}

result <- vcategorise(categories = segmentvalues, data = trialvec)
```

Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing `assignments` -- which is ok, even if at an index that doesn't have a value, that just gives you `NULL` -- and then indexing into what you get there -- which *won't* work if you get `NULL`. And `NULL` you will get, because you haven't allocated the list to be the right size.

In any case, I don't think it is necessary for you to allocate a table. You are already using a flat indexing structure in your test data generation, so why not do the same with `assignment` and then set its dimensions afterwards?

Something like this, perhaps?

```
 vcategorise <- function(categories, data) {
     assignment <- vector("list", length = length(data) * length(categories))
     n <- length(data)
     for (i in 1:length(categories)){
         for (j in 1:length(data)) {
             assignment[(i-1)*n + j] <- 
                 if (any(contains(categories[i], 
                                  ignore.case = TRUE,
                                  as.vector(data[j])))) {
                     data[j]
                 } else {
                     NA
                 }
         }
     }

     dim(assignment) <- c(length(data), length(categories))
     assignment
 }
```

It is not the prettiest code, but without fully understanding what you want to achieve, I don't know how to go further.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I'll have a proper look at this code in the morning. I want to find a way of categorising based on values in the data from a list of data frames, such that, say I can run a model on all data frames in the list with '1_P' as their categorisation. My current way of doing this is to create a list the same length as the input, such that it can be used as an index with a which(x....) type of function. Thanks again, and I hope that makes sense.